# image resolution for PPT and Photoshop

Tags: image-resizing

Scenario - I have to create some graphics which will be compatible with PPT and photoshop also with same size and same resolution

Issue - When am creating the graphics of 4 X 3 inch in PPT, importing it in photoshop becomes graphics of other size and vice versa.

My approach - I have tried to keep the common resolution but still not getting the desired result.

Please advise

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily after a long research I got the solution.

Initially I was creating the graphics in a box of X by Y (say 4 X 3) in the slide. And upon exporting the graphics to Photoshop it becomes graphics of another size. So instead of creating the frame of 4 X 3,  Its better to resize the slide itself. Better to create the graphics in slide of size 4 X 3 instead of frame of 4 X 3. and then export the complete slide to Photoshop. This solution worked perfectly for me